# How to make wildcard character.* work in shell script

Tags: shell, glob

I want to loop over files in some directories, I tried

```
INPUT_PATH=/group/had/muon/cometmgr/MC6/MC6A01/rootracker/oa_g4_proton_00000`printf %03d ${j}`*.rootracker
```

where j is increasing during the loop, but the output of `INPUT_PATH` is just a path including the character `*` but not replaced by file name. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Jens already gave a correct answer (please consider accepting it!), but the question is, what you want to achieve. Assume that the asterisk *would* be filename-expanded, but if there is more than one matching file - which one should be taken for `INPUT_PATH`? I suggets that you loop over the *.rootracker files and store the filename inside the loop body. If there is more than one matching file, you can detect this situation and act depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because variable assignments do not undergo filename expansion (aka *globbing*). According to POSIX, 2.9.1 Simple Commands:

> Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal prior to assigning the value.

You could use `eval` to get around it, but the SO commentariat will crucify me for suggesting it, since unless you're careful it can be a security risk.

Show us some more of what you want to do and we can suggest a better way. Until then, what about

```
INPUT_PATH=/group/had/muon/cometmgr/MC6/MC6A01/rootracker
for j in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do
  frob ${INPUT_PATH}/$(printf %03d $j)*.rootracker
done
```

should do the trick.